# Read from observable to other observables, but dont update the original?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Original observable which is read from:

```
self.searchResult = ko.observable(new Class());
```

3 "identical" observables which are read to:

```
self.address1 = ko.observable(new AddressClass());
self.address2 = ko.observable(new AddressClass());
self.address3 = ko.observable(new AddressClass());
```

Each of the address* observables have their own view/form through which they are updated. When opening the view the current address observable value is set to **self.searchResult.addresses[0]**.

The problem is that when updating any of the address* observables the original **self.searchResult.addresses[0]** is also updated.

Maybe a silly question, but I have spent some time trying to solve it with no luck, so any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So, if I follow what you're trying to explain, you likely have code similar to the following:

```
self.address1(self.searchResult.addresses[0]);
```

And this is called when populating the view for editing address1.

Thus, when address1 is edited on this view, the `self.address1` observable is updated, but so is `self.searchResult.addresses[0]`, and I'm guessing that you wanted `self.searchResult.addresses[0]` to remain unchanged so you can reference it to see what changed, or some similar scenario.

If I've got this right, then what you'll want to do is something equivalent to the following:

```
var searchResultAddress = self.searchResult.addresses[0];
var address1ToEdit = new AddressClass();
address1ToEdit.addressLine1(searchResultAddressInJS.addressLine1);
address1ToEdit.addressLine2(searchResultAddressInJS.addressLine2);
address1ToEdit.city(searchResultAddressInJS.city);
address1ToEdit.country(searchResultAddressInJS.country);
// etc...
self.address1(address1ToEdit);
```

If the properties of the address held by `self.searchResult.addresses[0]` are also observables, then you'll likely need to change that first line to the following:

```
var searchResultAddress = ko.toJS(self.searchResult.addresses[0]);
```

The key is to populate the address that's being populated for the view with an AddressClass that was populated with values that are not observables elsewhere.

Hope this helps.  However, if this answer doesn't quite get you there, just let me know, and I'd be happy to help you further, but at that point, a fiddle would help.

Comment: I tried that, but not working. I'm also using ko.mapping plugin, maybe that is the issue?

Comment: possibly, but again, it's hard for me to say without seeing the code.  can you provide a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?